# Paste files from list of paths into single output file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, paste, xargs

I have a file containing a list of filenames and their paths, as in the example below:

```
$ cat ./filelist.txt
/trunk/data/9.20.txt
/trunk/data/9.30.txt
/trunk/data/50.3.txt
/trunk/data/55.100.txt
...
```

All of these files, named as `X.Y.txt`, contain a list of double values. For example:

```
$ cat ./9.20.txt
1.23
1.0e-6
...
```

I'm trying to paste all of these `X.Y.txt` files into a single file, but I'm not sure about how to do it. Here's what I've been able to do so far:

```
cat ./filelist.txt | xargs paste output.txt >> output.txt
```

Any ideas on how to do it properly?

Comment: Note that `paste` doesn't just concatenate files, but places corresponding lines from its input files on a *single* output line, separated by tabs.

Comment: It would be useful to edit your question to elucidate whether you really meant to ask about the ``paste`` command or you meant ``cat``,  because some answers seem to assume you meant to just concatenate the files.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply `cat`-append each file into your output file, as in:

```
$ cat <list_of_paths> | xargs -I {} cat {} >> output.txt
```

In the above command, each line from your input file will be taken by `xargs`, and will be used to replace `{}`, so that each actual command being run is:

```
$ cat <X.Y.txt> >> output.txt
```

Comment: Nice. Turns out that `>` is enough for output redirection in this case (no need for `>>` due to use of `xargs`, though either works). If we also use *input* redirection, we get: `xargs -I {} cat {} < filelist.txt > output.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

#### More complex but without argument length limit

Well, the limit here is the available computer memory.

The file `buffer.txt` must not exist already.

```
touch buffer.txt
cat filelist.txt | xargs -iXX bash -c 'paste buffer.txt XX > output.txt; mv output.txt buffer.txt'; 
mv buffer.txt output.txt
```

What this does, by line:

1. Create a `buffer.txt` file which must be initially empty. (`paste` does not seem to like non-existent files. There does not seem to be a way to make it treat such files as empty.)
2. Run `paste buffer.txt XX > output.txt; mv output.txt buffer.txt`. `XX` is replaced by each file in the `filelist.txt` file. You can't just do `paste buffer.txt XX > buffer.txt` because `buffer.txt` will be truncated before `paste` processes it. Hence the `mv` rigmarole.
3. Move `buffer.txt` to `output.txt` so that you get your output with the file name you wanted. Also makes it safe to rerun the whole process.

The previous version forced xargs to issue exactly one `paste` per file you want to paste but for even better performance, you can do this:

```
touch buffer.txt; 
cat filelist.txt | xargs bash -c 'paste buffer.txt "$@" > output.txt; mv output.txt buffer.txt' FILLER; 
mv buffer.txt output.txt
```

Note the presence of `"$@"` in the command that `bash` executes. So `paste` gets the list of arguments from the list of arguments given to bash. The `FILLER` parameter passed to `bash` is to give it a value for `$0`. If it were not there, then the first file that `xargs` gives to bash would be used for `$0` and thus `paste` would skip some files.

This way, `xargs` can pass hundreds of parameters to `paste` with each invocation and thus reduce dramatically the number of times `paste` is invoked.

#### Simpler but limited way

**This method suffer from limitations on the number of arguments that a shell can pass to a command it executes**. However, in many cases it is good enough. I can't count the number of times when I was performing spur-of-the-moment operations where using `xargs` would have been superfluous. (As part of a long term solution, that's another matter.)

The simpler way is:

```
paste `cat filelist.txt` > output.txt
```

It seems you were thinking that `xargs` would execute `paste output.txt >> output.txt` multiple times but that's not how it works. The redirection applies to the entire `cat ./filelist.txt | xargs paste output.txt` (as you initially had it). If you want to have redirection apply to the individual commands launched by `xargs` you have it launch a shell, like I do above.

Comment: I personally prefer to avoid cat for non-interactive (as in, scripts) use, because bash almost always seems to interpret what cat parses, as a literal command to be executed.

Comment: A valiant effort, but I suspect the OP was looking for simple concatenation and had a misconception about what the `paste` utility does. Either way, I suggest you preface your bona-fide `paste` answer accordingly to distinguish it from the `cat`-based ones.

Comment: @petrus4: You may have a misconception there: there is no interpretation involved when redirecting output from `cat` to a file.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking to do is to read each line from `filelist.txt` and append the contents of the file that the line refers to to a single output file, use this:

```
while read -r file; do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] && cat "$file"
done < "filelist.txt" > "output.txt"
```

Edit: If you know your input file to *only* contain lines that are file paths (and optionally empty lines) - and no comments, etc. - @Rubens' `xargs`-based solution is the simplest.

The advantage of the `while` loop is that you can pre-process each line from the input file, as demonstrated by the `-f` test above, which ensures that the input line refers to an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

while read -r 
do
echo "${REPLY}" >> output.txt
done < filelist.txt
```

OR, to get the files directly:-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

find *.txt -type f | while read $files
do
echo "${files}" >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: By simply `echo`ing the input file path to the combined output file, all you're doing is creating a *copy* of the input file. You need to use `cat` rather than `echo` in order to append the files' *contents* to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `while` loop should do the trick:

```
while read line; do
   cat ${line} >> output.txt
done < filelist.txt
```